# Upload files from multiple forms is not working using multipart/form-data

Tags: jquery, ajax, multipartform-data, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to upload files from different forms to the server. The problem is that the upload method is not working properly. The mystery is that if i debug with breakpoints on the firebug the it works fine. Below is my html block:

```
<form class="omics_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">                                

            <div class="form_block">
                <div class="form_header">Select photo</div>
                <input type="file" class="photo_file" accept="image/*">
                <a href="#" class="remove_omics_just">clear</a>
            </div>

            <div class="form_block">
                <div class="form_header">Description</div>
                <input type = "text" class="photo_descr">
            </div>
</form>

<form class="clinical_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <div class="form_block">
                <div class="form_header">Select photo</div>
                <input type="file" class="photo_file" accept="image/*">
                <a href="#" class="remove_clinical_just">clear</a>
            </div>

            <div class="form_block">
                <div class="form_header">Description</div>
                <input type = "text" class="photo_descr">
            </div>                       
</form>
```

Now my jquery thing is this (Note that maybe there is more than two forms) :

```
$.each(all_clinical_forms, function(index, value){
               if (extension === 'jpg' || extension === 'png' || extension === 'bmp' || extension === 'tif') {

                    formData.append("image_file", image_file);
                    var JSON_object = {
                        "submission_id": submission_id,
                        "id": clinical_id,
                        "descr": description,
                        "is_clinical": "true"
                    };
                    var JSON_string = JSON.stringify(JSON_object);


                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/delegate/UploadPhoto?JSON=" + JSON_string,
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        beforeSend: function(xhr){
                            if (xhr.overrideMimeType)
                            {
                                xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");
                            }
                        },
                        success: function(data) {

                        },
                        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("Error trying upload the file.");
                        },
                        // Form data
                        data: formData,
                        //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false                        
                    });

                } else {
                    alert('The file '+file_name+' is not an image format.');                
                }
}

$.each(all_omics_forms, function(index, value){    

    if (extension === 'jpg' || extension === 'png' || extension === 'bmp' || extension ===     'tif') {

                    formData.append("image_file", image_file);
                    var JSON_object = {
                        "submission_id": submission_id,
                        "id": omics_id,
                        "descr": description,
                        "is_clinical": "false"
                    };
                    var JSON_string = JSON.stringify(JSON_object);                    


                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/delegate/UploadPhoto?JSON=" + JSON_string,
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        beforeSend: function(xhr){
                            if (xhr.overrideMimeType)
                            {
                                xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");
                            }
                        },
                        success: function(data) {

                        },
                        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("Error trying upload the file.");
                        },
                        // Form data
                        data: formData,
                        //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false
                    }); 



}
```

As i said when i call the servlet only one image is uploaded. The mysterious thing is that if i set a breakpoint on every ajax call through firebug then the images are uploaded fine. Maybe it is a matter of time? I am really stacked here and very confused. 
Any help or suggestion?

Comment: If something works with added breakpoints and not without, that is often a sign that some asynchronous method gets called, but the processing does not respect that and is scripted in a linear way instead.